# How to make local storage key value default to a local JSON file in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

Playing around with localStorage in React by making a very simple to-do app. I've found examples of localStorage hooks like [this one](https://blog.logrocket.com/using-localstorage-react-hooks/):

```
function getStorageValue(key, defaultValue) {
  // getting stored value
  const saved = localStorage.getItem(key);
  const initial = JSON.parse(saved);
  return initial || defaultValue;
}

export const useLocalStorage = (key, defaultValue) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(() => {
    return getStorageValue(key, defaultValue);
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    // storing input name
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
  }, [key, value]);

  return [value, setValue];
};
```

I understand this but I'm trying to figure out how to set the defaultvalue to be a key value fetched and parsed from a local file.

Like this:

`const [name, setName] = useLocalStorage("name", JSON file data);`

Comment: What do you mean by local file? A file provided by a user?

Comment: No, a JSON file in the React public folder. @KonradLinkowski

Comment: Better put that file inside src folder and just import it like this `import data from "./data.json"`, data will be an object representing the JSON itself.

Comment: @niceman Yeah that's what I did! Thanks.